# For loop won't add terms for some reason

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, pi

So, I was putting my knowledge of for loops to the test by attempting to create the mathematical constant π using a series with user-defined accuracy:

```
public double pi(int accuracy) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= accuracy; i++) {
        rawPi += 1 / (i * i);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(rawPi * 6);
}
```

Now, you would think that this would get closer and closer to π as `int accuracy` shoots up, but it doesn't. It just stays at the square root of 6, meaning that `private double rawPi` gets to 1 and never goes any higher, meaning no terms are being added in my series (represented as a for loop) and I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be. Any ideas?

Comment: To expand on @SotiriosDelimanolis's comment, the loop is adding just fine. The problem is that, due to the integer division, the second and subsequent iterations are adding 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
    rawPi += 1 / (i * i);
```

to

```
    rawPi += 1.0 / (i * i);
```

or as commented by "Patricia Shanahan" , use this for better accuracy and to avoid integer overflow on i*i:

```
1/((double)i*i)
```

Comment: Depending on accuracy, `1/((double)i*i)` may be better, to avoid integer overflow on `i*i`.

Comment: You need to declare rawPi as double

Comment: Declare it and initial it in to zero.

Comment: Thanks, Juned. I changed `int i` to `double i` and it works perfectly now.